# How to change ISO volume label on OS X?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem

I have some ISO files here with weird volume labels. I want to rename them to something I can easily remember.

I know in Windows using either winiso or poweriso (both are non-free?) it can be done but I'm not so sure in OS X. I did search the net but nothing useful came up.

Comment: How about this answer? Seems like it should work with your situation. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45015/84062

Comment: This is something entirely different.

Comment: just tried. doesn't work. Could not touch /Volumes/G2_28201//.disk_label
Could not write scale 1 bitmap label file